# Will I be able to send push notifications to APNS if have port 2195 opened but 2196 blocked?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The security team of my company is reluctant to open the above two ports.
After going through the [Apple docs](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203609), I can see that the port 2195 is for sending the push notifications, and 2196 is for feedback service.

If I only use port 2195 to just send the push, and not care for the feedback service, will I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send the push to APNS if only the port 2195 is opened. Port 2196 is only for Feedback service.